# Implementing UITableViewDelegate methods in UITableViewDataSource extension

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, tableview

As we know, we implement Delegates for custom actions in another class and we implement DataSources for supplying custom data to a class. But why we can implement UITableViewDelegate methods in UITableViewDataSource extension? like below image. If I`m not mistaken I have to implement didDeselect method in UITableViewDelegate instead of UITableViewDataSource but Xcode allows me to do that. Please guide me. Thank you

[image]

Comment: extensions are what you write for convenience. If you remove the first extension and try, it won't show up. Since your have already implemented the protocol in the extension before this one, it is also a part of this one. (Actually everything is part of the same class that you make) You can also implement delegates of this Protocol in that extension that you made.

Comment: Oh yeah, I got your point. Thank you Rakesha Shastri